# Parsing string from the name

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to parse the certain name from the filename.

The examples of File names are

```
xs_1234323_00_32

sf_12345233_99_12

fs_01923122_12_12
```

I used `String parsedname= child.getName().substring(4.9)` to get the 1234323 out of the first line. Instead, how do I format it for the above 3 to output only the middle numbers(between the two _)? Something using `split`?

Comment: using String.split('_') maybe? This will return an array of strings.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)  `fname.split("_")[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String [] tokens = filename.split("_");
/*  xs_1234323_00_32 would be
      [0]=>xs   [1]=> 1234323   [2]=> 00  [3] => 32
*/
String middleNumber = tokens[2];
```

Comment: Pretty sure it'll be at index 1, but this is basically it.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan didnt know which "middle number" he meant. There are two numbers that are between "_" haha

Answer (score 2):

one line solution

```
String n = str.replaceAll("\\D+(\\d+).+", "$1");
```

most efficent solution

```
    int i  = str.indexOf('_');
    int j = str.indexOf('_', i + 1);
    String n = str.substring(i + 1, j);
```

Comment: As much as I love regex, this is like using a bazooka to hunt geese.

Comment: I think it's more economical than splitting into a String array taking only one element and throwing away the rest

Comment: In the same way that using a bazooka is more economical than having to fish out the bullet and pluck the feathers. ;c)

Comment: But Spring.split is implemented as Pattern.compile(regex).split internally

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't make them equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
filename.split("_", 3)[1]
```

The second argument of [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) indicates the maximum number of pieces the string should be split into, in your case you only need 3. This will be faster than using the single-argument version of `split`, which will continue splitting on the delimiter unnecessarily.

Comment: I had downvoted this, but removed my vote.  THis isn't significantly different enough from @75inchpianist's answer.

Comment: I'm aware of what the second argument of .split does, and my comment stands.  Your edit is needlessly pedantic.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan I don't understand how you can say that this is not sufficiently different than the other answer, let alone pedantic. And I don't care if *you* know what the second argument of `split` does, the point is to enlighten the OP; the two argument version of `split` is a very underused yet useful tool of the `String` class, and is perfect for this circumstance.

Comment: because there are only four possible splits in the problem statement.  Adding a limit creates zero operational efficiency in this case.  And because string copying is linear, it only creates operational efficiency when you have a very complex regular expression.  Since the expression here is a single character, You're not helping in a noticeable way.

Comment: I think what Frank means is that for *small* inputs this would fall under micro-optimisation.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan When such a minute addition (in this case the `3` argument) helps even at the microscopic level, it would be foolish not to use it. I would agree with you if readability was hindered or we had to go out of our way to make the change, but this is as simple as can be. Furthermore, this allows for greater flexibility if the input values are ever changed.

Comment: Your answer by all means is correct. Perhaps, that's why Frank withdrew his down-vote. But, whether it offers significant benefits over the other is debatable. No offence.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I respectfully disagree, in accordance with my extensive comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using split using the '_' delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) methods splits this string around matches of the given ;parameter. So use like this

```
String[] output = input.split("_");
```

here `output[1]` will be your desired result

ANd input will be like

```
String input = "xs_1234323_00_32"
```

Comment: Well, what error does it give you?  What type of variable is 'child'?

Comment: @user2475261: because you probably need `child.getName().split("_")`.  Also you should use backticks `\`` to highlight code in the comments.

Comment: Actually I get this error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at okay.OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:54)